# Return column name where Join condition is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 tables: Employee and Person with the structure

```
Employee: Id, PersonId, Designation, IsActive
Person:Id, Name, Contact
```

Employee's PersonId column references Person's Id and can be null

I need to return an employee's Name and my join criteria is

```
SELECT emp.Salary, emp.Designation, emp.IsActive, p.Name from Employee emp
JOIN Person P ON P.Id = emp.PersonId or (p.Id is NULL AND emp.Id IS NULL)
```

This is incorrect as my requirement is:

```
If emp.PersonId = null, return p.Name = NULL
else return p.Name = Person's Name from table
```

Any pointers on this?

Comment: I'm kind of concered that you could have an employee who is not in the person table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an outer join

```
SELECT emp.Salary, emp.Designation, emp.IsActive, p.Name 
from Employee emp
left JOIN Person P 
ON P.Id = emp.PersonId
```

when you use an INNER JOIN (or JOIN) you only select the rows matching the join critiria, in your example you would never nave a NULL Person name because if the Employee is not assiciated with a Person, that record would not be selected.

If you use OUTER JOIN (LEFT/RIGHT JOIN), ALL record from the main table (1st with LEFT and 2nd with RIGHT) will be selected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite. This is because one of the Join conditions (Id) could be NULL and if ID not null return Name else empty.